# Не приходит Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON при нажатии клавиш bluetooth - гарнитуры

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcast-receiver, android-intent

У меня наблюдается сложность: не приходят `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` в ресивер по нажатию аппаратной кнопки блутуз -гарнитуры. Ресивер зарегестрирован корректно

```
<receiver android:name="com.mypackage.receivers.BluetoothReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    public BluetoothReceiver() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)) {
            ...
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Для обработки нажатия кнопок гарнитуры вот такой вот код :

```
 ComponentName mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(App.getAppContext(),BluetoothReceiver.class);
 mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(App.getAppContext(), "MY_TAG",
                mediaButtonReceiver, null);
 mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
 mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
     @Override
     public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
         Log.i("TAG","media button event");
             return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonEvent);
         }
     });
 mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

Но у меня не вызывается ни onMediaButtonEvent(), ни onReceive() по нажатию на кнопку гарнитуры. 
Я так же пробовал способ, содержащий deprecated методы,он тоже не работает.

```
manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(App.getAppContext(), BluetoothReceiver.class);
manager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver);
```

Что я могу делать неправильно ?Почему может не приходить интент?(Тестил код на нескольких bt-гарнитурах)

Comment: Попробуйте поставить для priority 999. *android:priority* The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000.

Comment: Результат тот же. приходят только  интенты BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED и 
AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED  по нажатию на   кнопку гарнитуры

Comment: собственно.. ранее они тоже приходили ( до правок приоритета)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, все просто, меняешь местами строчки `mediaSession.setFlags` и `mediaSession.setCallback` и всё начинает работать. Ну по крайней мере, у меня именно в такой последовательности всё работает.